# JMS Serializer adding subscriber/listener changes output

Tags: symfony, entity, listener, jmsserializerbundle

I have an Entity with multiple child entities of different classes.

Using this code it all works correctly

```
$serializer = SerializerBuilder::create()->build();
```

But as soon as I add this

```
$serializer = SerializerBuilder::create()
    ->configureListeners(function(EventDispatcher $dispatcher) {
        $dispatcher->addSubscriber(new CustomSubscriber());
    })
->build();
```

The output for some of the child objects changes from the correct attributes to

```
"attribute": {
    "id": 1,
    "__initializer__": {},
    "__cloner__": {},
    "__is_initialized__": false,
    "lazy_properties_defaults": []
}
```

Its not all of them, its just some of them. The FOSUser object is correct, but my own Entities are now missing all their fields, apart from the ID.

How do I use a subscriber/listener and ensure my Entities do not change?

Answer (score 1):

Found it, not obvious or documented!

```
$serializer = SerializerBuilder::create()
    ->configureListeners(function(EventDispatcher $dispatcher) {
        $dispatcher->addSubscriber(new CustomSubscriber());
    })
->addDefaultListeners()
->build();
```

Comment: That code looks exactly the same as what is in your original post, was it meant to be different?

Comment: Sometimes, only sometimes, copy & paste gets the better of me. Updated now. :-)